# Как получить несколько таблиц на rest api на yii2

Tags: php, yii2, rest

У меня есть TableName1, TableName2, TableName3 и я хочу получить их по запросу например:

```
myDomain.com/api/tablename1
myDomain.com/api/tablename2
myDomain.com/api/tablename3
```

как я понял это

```
public $modelClass = 'app\models\TableName1';
```

Подключает одну таблицу. Как я могу подключить несколько таблиц в одном контроллере.

Нельзя же для каждого запроса отдельный контроллер создать пожалуйста подскажите с примерами

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Для получения связанных объектов, необходимо в запросе указать список этих объектов, используя параметр expand, на пример 
`api/user/?expand=profile` 
вернет список юзеров с профайлами, более подробно описано  [тут](https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/rest-resources/)

Comment: они друг с другом несвязана. мне нужно вернут json для мобил приложения я решил это проблема создав отделный контроллер и вернул резултат в формате json

Answer (score 0):

Для того что бы посылать информации из своего сайта на приложение или другых цел нужна создать контролер и в нём экшеный каторый отвечаеть отделный таблицы. На это контроллер добавить **behaviours** что бы передать их в виде json.

```
$behaviors['contentNegotiator'] = [
        'class' => \yii\filters\ContentNegotiator::className(),
        'formats' => [
            'application/json' => \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON,
        ],
    ];
```

Пример на фото:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

http://domain.com/api/one
http://domain.com/api/two/1 или http://domain.com/api/two?id=1 зависить вашего чпу.